# How configure tomcat 7 SSL to use AES-NI?

Tags: tls, linux, openssl

My server has AES-NI and I would like tomcat 7 to make use of this but I am not really sure how to make that happen or where to even start looking. I am quite familiar with tomcat administration, and understand the various connectors that tomcat makes available. Tomcat is running on CentOS 6.3 and Oracle Java 7 update 15.

Here are some of my questions.

1. What SSL cipher suites will benefit from AES-NI?
2. Can it be turned on with Oracle Java 7 update 15?
3. If using the tomcat native connectors that are based on the apache APR and openssl what do I have to do to turn it on?
4. Will AES-NI increase SSL performance significantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your last question. No, AES-NI will not increase your SSL performance significantly. A CPU which has the [AES-NI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instructions can encrypt data *without using these instructions* at a rate of more than 120 MB/s (probably more than 200 MB/s on a server), i.e. more than 10 (or 20) times what 100 MBit/s ethernet can provide. Correspondingly, the best you can hope for, at the best of times and with a supremely efficient hardware implementation of AES, is to save less than 10% (or 5%) on CPU. That's not "significant". Since you use Tomcat to process the data, I seriously doubt that the encryption cost of AES is even detectable on your server. Sure, with AES-NI the processor can encrypt 15 times faster, but since encryption already uses a negligible overall amount of CPU, what would be the point ?

A much quoted data point is what Google said when [they switched Gmail to site-wide SSL](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html): they measured a CPU load increase by a meagre +1%. Of course, impact may vary on site type and amount of processing for each request, but we can keep that in mind: **SSL is cheap**. Making it cheaper will not offer tremendous gains.

Now, for your other questions, the implementation of AES which uses AES-NI instructions should be automatically selected (without needing any configuration on your part) if all of the following are true:

- The CPU supports the AES-NI instructions.
- The actual implementation of AES (as used in SSL) is [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).
- That version of OpenSSL is 1.0.1 or later.

Thus, if you use Tomcat behind `mod_ssl` (in Apache) *and* your local OpenSSL library is recent enough, then you already benefit from AES-NI goodness. If you do the SSL with Tomcat itself (thus relying on Java's internal cryptography), then chances are that you end up with some Java code which does *not* benefit from AES-NI -- but this would deserve investigation (namely benchmarks). My opinion is that it will make no measurable difference whatsoever anyway, so the point is kinda moot.